# How to unselect a multiselect field in my custom modul edit page?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, multiselect

I have added a multiselect field to a fieldset in my form.xml.

```
        <column name="ghs_pictogram_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Mcas\GhsPictogram\Source\Pictogram</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">int</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Pictogram</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

It works fine, I can select values and they are stored. My Problem is, that I'm not able to unselect the field. Once it is selected it stores a value, a reset to empty is not possible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try below code  .

```
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>
```

Comment: Thank you, I yust tried it, but it is not working. If once I have clicked a value in the multiselect field, the value is marked. It is not possible to unmark the value, only if I choose another value. But this is not helpful. Do you have an idea???

Comment: For a select field I can add a caption in the config section.

Comment: <config>
.....
<item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select one...</item>
.....
</config>